# Displaying data from a json file in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-controller

This questions has been answered on a different post. See here: [Displaying json data in an Angular App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532230/displaying-json-data-in-an-angular-app)

Comment: The json data will not display, simple arithmethic expressions would even fail to compute within the controller div.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the demo http://dojo.telerik.com/UkUbE

```
 var app =angular.module('PhoneCat',[]);
app.factory('info', ['$http', function($http){ 
  var data = {};
  data.getInfo = $http.get('http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/angular-phonecat/master/app/phones/phones.json')
  .success(function(data){
     return data;
  })
   .error(function(err){
     return err;
   });

  return data;

 }]);
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope','info',
function($scope, info) {
info.getInfo.then(function(res){
    $scope.datar = res.data;
 });  
}]);
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: For me the `success` and `error` methods in info service are useless

Comment: The code above seem to work, I believe the error has to do with the specific json feed I'm trying to work with (which doesn't seem to work), this: https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK