# Displaying json data in an Angular App

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-services, angular-controller

I am trying to parse data from a json file and display it in my angular application, but for some odd reason the view wouldn't show the data(intepret my expressions), I thought it might be my controller, but it looks fine. Any help would be appreciated in solving this, thanks.

Below is the code for my Http Service:

```
app.factory('info', ['$http', function($http){ 
  return 
  $http.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
      .success(function(data){
         return data;
      })
       .error(function(err){
         return err;
       });
}]);
```

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope','info',
 function($scope) {
    info.success(function(data){
        $scope.datar = data;
  });  
}]);
```

And this is my view:

```
<div class="main" >
  <div class="container" >
  <div class="photo" >
  <div ng-controller="HomeController" ng-repeat="data in datar">
    <p1>{{data.age}}</p1>
   <p1>{{name.modified}}</p1>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are querying JSONP endpoint you need to use [$http.jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) method. And very important: put `$http.jsonp` on the **same** line after `return`, otherwise [automatic semicolon insertion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) turns it into `return;` basically returning `undefined`.

```
app.factory('info', ['$http', function($http) { 
  return $http.jsonp('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?&format=json&jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK')
      .then(function(response) {
          return response.data;
      });
}]);
```

Note parameter name `jsoncallback`, not just "callback".

After that your controller should also use `then` instead of success (it's deprecated):

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'info', function($scope, info) {
    info.then(function(data) {
        $scope.datar = data;
    });  
}]);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/yFomQ8jOZDRS6mZSBkGx?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have just done this, but still doesn't display in my view. Got any more ideas?

Comment: @CodeArt Check the demo, the main problem was GET parameter name, `jsoncallback` instead of just "callback".

Comment: You're also not fully injecting the `info` Service in your controller. Add `info` inside `function($scope)` as well so it'd be `function($scope, info)`.

Comment: @Shane Thanks indeed.

Comment: @dfsq You are just great! Your version totally works. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Shane your additions was spot on, the above code didn't work untill I did what you suggested. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see u are returning data. In AngularJS there are no synchronous calls.

You need to return a promise

```
app.factory('info', ['$http', '$q'], function($http, $q){ 

    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
           .success(function(data){
               defer.resolve(data);
           })
           .error(function(err){
               defer.reject(err);
          });

    return defer.promise;
}]);
```

But then you also have to change your controller to:

```
info.then(function (res) {
    $scope.datar = res;
},function(err) {
    // hande error
})
```

Comment: Could you confirm you've ran this code successfully(?), as I believe the api_key might be the issue.

Comment: I believe that request will be sent as soon as you inject factory into controller what is actually side effect. Please create get method in factory to teach him how to properly define such factories.

Comment: I re-wrote my code exactly as above, not sucess either. But Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The $http service will return a response having following properties:

```
data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.
```

also I think your factory should look like this:

```
app.factory('info', ['$http', function($http){ 
  return {
        get : function(){ 
  $http.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
}}}]);
```

and in the controller

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope','info',
 function($scope) {
    info.get()
  .success(function(response){
        $scope.datar = response.data;
  })
  .error(function(data) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });  
}]);
```

if you are using google chrome you could try right click -> inspect element, you will see if there are some errors, or you could put breakpoints in javascript to see exactly what data you receive.

I recommend as further reading:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service

Comment: Thanks for that, I would have to read those documentations, the code above didn't work either :/